# How to import Apache Flink SNAPSHOT artifacts?

Tags: java, maven, apache-flink, gelly

I want to add the documents of Gelly to my project, but it gives me this error:

> Sources not found for: org.apache.flink:flink-gelly_2.10:1.2-SNAPSHOT

This is in my **pom.xml**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
    <artifactId>flink-gelly_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>1.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

I tried looking for a different version of gelly to solve this issue but couldn't find any. is there any other way to get the documentation?

Answer (score 7):

Apache publishes `SNAPSHOT` artifacts only to a dedicated Maven repository. Note that these artifacts are only meant for development purposes. They are *not* part of an official Apache Flink release!

You have to add the following repository configuration to your `pom.xml` to receive `SNAPSHOT` artifacts:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>apache.snapshots</id>
      <name>Apache Development Snapshot Repository</name>
      <url>https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
      <releases><enabled>false</enabled></releases>
      <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
   </repository>
</repositories>
```

Alternatively, you can download the latest Flink code and build it on your local machine.

Comment: Thnx! that worked, there is nothing wrong with Flink, but with Gelly, i'm using the snapshots because i couldn't find any other version in the documentation.

Comment: Gelly is part of Flink since several releases, the latest being Flink 1.1.2. So `<version>1.1.2</version>` should work without the snapshot repository.

Comment: I have these dependancies added in Intellij:
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-java</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
       ...(and the other 2 for streaming and clinets)
But when i don't include the Gelly dependancies it won't recognize the gelly library functions

Comment: Maybe you are using features that have not been released yet. In that case you need to stick with the SNAPSHOT version until 1.2.0 is released.